# FluentMigrator - Check if column exists cross database

Tags: c#, sql, fluent-migrator

I'm using FluentMigrator to migrate multiple databases to different schemas.

How can I check if a column exists in a table in another database?

```
public override void Up()
{
    //this line by default uses the current DB context and it works fine
    var columnExistsInThisDb = Schema.Table("Subjects").Column("MatterKey").Exists();

    //here I would like to check if column exist in "AnotherDatabase", 
    //but I didn't manage to make it work
    var columnExistsInAnotherDb = 

            Database("AnotherDatabase") //<--- this is pseudo-code of what I would like to achieve 
                .Schema.Table("Subjects").Column("MatterKey").Exists();


    if (columnExistsInThisDb || columnExistsInAnotherDb)
    {
        Execute.Sql("--DO STUFF");
    }
}
```

I have tried the below, but it returns FALSE even if the colum exists.

```
var columnExistsInAnotherDb = Schema.Table("AnotherDatabase.dbo.Subjects").Column("MatterKey").Exists()
```

Answer (score 0):

In general It's bad idea. Fluent migrator should handle schema by itself. In other case - there's no reason to use it. I'll recommend you to use [fluent migrator tags](https://fluentmigrator.github.io/articles/migration/migration-filter-tags.html?tabs=runner-internal). They are created for handling different databases.

But if you really want to do it as you described - here's example how to call database script (all that stuff you'll get from parent class):

```
Execute.WithConnection((IDbConnection connection, IDbTransaction transaction) =>
            {
                var command = connection.CreateCommand();
                command.Transaction = transaction;
                command.CommandText = "SELECT * " +
                       "FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS " +
                       "WHERE table_name = 'tableName' " +
                       "AND table_schema = 'schema'" + 
                       "AND column_name = 'columnName'";
                var count = command.ExecuteScalar();
            });
```

Comment: You are right, but in my case, I have an edge case in which I need to check if that column exist in both DBs.  Your answer is good inspiration though. Thanks.

Comment: So my second option should work for you)